# Beautifulsoup getting attributes following class name

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'll preface this by saying I'm relatively new to beautiful soup.  I understand that the following line:

```
soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'favorite_links')[0]
```

will get me the entire contents of the first div tag where class = favorite-links.  However what I actually want is text that is immediately to the right of the class name:

```
    <div class="favorite-links" data-can-favorite="" data-id="10820653">
</div>
```

What I hope to get is the numbers after data-id.  Is there a way to do this?  I could definitely do it using string operations but I want to know whether there is a way to do this specifically using BeautifulSoup

Sorry in advance for my poor terminology.  As I said before I'm relatively new to BeautifulSoup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
soup.find_all('div', class_="favorite-links")[0]['data-id']
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to incorporate it into a list comprehension such that I get all data-ids in the html?

Comment: my attempt which isn't working:  [t for t in soup.find_all(class_='favorite-links')[t]['data-id']]

Comment: `[a['data-id'] for a in soup.find_all('div', class_="favorite-links")`

Comment: ahh gotcha, that implementation makes sense! Thanks!